# JS как передать аргумент в качестве ключа в словаре?

Tags: javascript, словари, async-await, dict, fetch

Не получается задать/передать аргумент companyId как ключ в словаре,подскажите как это можно сделать или варианты какие есть?

```js
  async addMatchFormToActivity(token, activityId, companyId, origin) {
    const data = {
      companyId: [
        {
          selectedEvaluation: [
            {
              label: 'AutomationTestingWithAPI ',
              value: 867,
              formName: 'index_#0',
            },
          ],
          selectedEM: [{ value: 13475, label: 'DoNotTouch' }],
        },
      ],
    }
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(
        `${text.baseApi}matching-state/${activityId}`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
            Origin: origin,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        },
      ).then((res) => res.json())
      return resp
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно использовать [вычисляемые ключи](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
    const data = {
      [companyId]: [
```

Comment: Спасибо! За подсказду)